# JavaScript onChange() on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, onchange

Is it possible to assign the same onChange() to multiple elements (no jQuery)

At the moment i'm doing

```
var namefirst = document.getElementsByName("attribute.Identifier Source")[0];
namefirst.onchange = function () {//disable some stuff }
```

However, I have to do this onChange() for another 5 elements, and so i was wondering if it's possible to do this for all of them at once? Or am I going to have to do this for each element.

(I'm very new to Javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to bind it at once, try using event delegation. i.e create a wrapper for the inputs and bind the change event to it, and detect the element based on event target and do your action.

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="myText" />
    <input type="text" name="myText" />
    <input type="text" name="myText" />
    <input type="text" name="myText" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('change', function(event){
    var elem = event.target;
    console.log(elem.name);
    console.log(elem.tagName);
    console.log(elem.type);
    if(elem.name === "myText"){
         console.log(elem.value);
    }   
});
```

So here the change event on input bubbles up to its parent and there you catch it and perform your operations.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFPLw/)**

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
var names = document.getElementsByName("attribute.Identifier Source");
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i].onchange = function() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is with a loop like this:

```
for(i=0; i<var.length; i++){
    //do stuff
}
```

but I don't understand your code so I can't be specific

if you want all elements with a name to have an onchange event then this is how you do it:

```
get=document.getElementsByName("someName");
for(i=0; i<get.length; i++){
       get[i].addEventListener("change", yourFunction, false);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you could loop over the elements and assign the handler inside the loop:

```
function onChangeHandler() {
  // do some stuff
}

var myCollection = document.getElementsByName("attribute.Identifier Source");
for (var i=0, l=myCollection.length; i<l; i++)
  myCollection[i] = onChangeHandler;
```

Or, if you would want to have a reference to the changed element:

```
function onChangeHandler(event) {
  // some browser abstraction
  if (!event) event = window.event;
  var changedElement = event.srcElement || this;
  // do some stuff
}

var myCollection = document.getElementsByName("attribute.Identifier Source");
for (var i=0, l=myCollection.length; i<l; i++) {
  myCollection[i].addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler, false);
  /* if you want to support older MSIE, you would do some like
  var el = myCollection[i];
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler, false);
  }
  else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('onchange', onChangeHandler);
  }
  */
}
```

Please note that document.getElementsByName() is only supported with XHTML, you may want to use document.querySelectorAll() or document.getElementsByTagName() ...

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate way in doing this sequentially. You can mark your html code with a pseudo-class and do the following:

```
var elems=document.querySelectorAll(".mark");
for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    elems[i].addEventListener("change", myFunction);
}
```

I would like to note that this method is not compatible with older browsers. For more info go
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).